# Fastest way to create DataFrame from last available data

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I had no success looking for answers for this question in the forum since it is hard to put it in keywords. Any keywords suggestions are appreciated so that I cane make this question more accessible so that others can benefit from it.

The closest [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231834/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-columns-of-other-dataframes-with-similar-indexe) I found doesn't really answer mine.

My problem is the following:

I have one DataFrame that I called `ref`, and a dates list called `pub`. `ref` has dates for indexes but those dates are different (there will be a few matching values) from the dates in `pub`. I want to create a new DataFrame that contains all the dates from `pub` but fill it with the "last available data" from `ref`.

Thus, say `ref` is:

```
Dat          col1 col2 
2015-01-01   5    4
2015-01-02   6    7
2015-01-05   8    9
```

And `pub`

```
2015-01-01
2015-01-04
2015-01-06
```

I'd like to create a DataFrame like:

```
Dat          col1 col2 
2015-01-01   5    4
2015-01-04   6    7
2015-01-06   8    9
```

For this matter performance is an issue. So i'm looking for the fastest / a fast way of doing that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need sequence(position) based replacement of vlaue in `Dat` column with a  `pub` list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an outer merge, set the new index to `Dat`, sort it, forward fill, and then reindex based on the dates in `pub`.

```
dates = ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-06']
pub = pd.DataFrame([dt.datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for ts in dates], 
                   columns=['Dat'])

>>> (ref
     .merge(pub, on='Dat', how='outer')
     .set_index('Dat')
     .sort_index()
     .ffill()
     .reindex(pub.Dat))
            col1  col2
Dat                   
2015-01-01     5     4
2015-01-04     6     7
2015-01-06     8     9
```

Comment: Hi Alexander thanks for the help. But ideally I would like the second row to display 6 and 7 not 8 and 9. Is that possible ?

Comment: Should be.  What types are your dates? Timestamps, python datetime objects, or strings?

Answer (score 2):

Use np.searchsorted for finding the indice just after ('right' option; needed to handle properly equality)  :

```
In [27]: pub = ['2015-01-01', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-06']

In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
            col1  col2
Dat                   
2015-01-01     5     4
2015-01-02     6     7
2015-01-05     8     9

In [29]: y=np.searchsorted(list(df.index),pub,'right')
#array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Then just rebuild :

```
In [30]: pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[y-1].values,index=pub)
Out[30]: 
            0  1
2015-01-01  5  4
2015-01-04  6  7
2015-01-06  8  9
```

Comment: i guess this solution should be faster - can you add a `timeit` comparison to your answer?