# keep the index of left join

Tags: python, pandas

I want to left join 2 dataframes using the below codes.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Mbr ID':[1,2,3],'Sales':[30,45,90]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Mbr ID':[2,3,4],'Qty':[7,3,8]})
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',left_on='Mbr ID',right_on='Mbr ID')
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)
```

How do I keep the index column of the 2nd dataframe after joining? This is so that I am able to remove non-matching Mbr IDs. The ideal outcome will be 2 Mbr ID columns in df3.

[image]

Comment: Check related - [Creating a pandas DataFrame from columns of other DataFrames with similar indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231834/creating-a-pandas-dataframe-from-columns-of-other-dataframes-with-similar-indexe?rq=1)

Comment: Why not `how='outer'`? You'll only have one `Mbr ID` column, but there will be `NaN` values in `Sales` or `Qty` depending on which DataFrame is missing values.