# python pandas - Append columns to an empty dataframe with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, append

I have 2 dataframes, `c_r` and `x`. I am trying to `append` an empty dataframe, with this code:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in c_r:
    for j in x:
        if c_r[i].dtype != object and x[j].dtype != object:
            if i == j:
                col_c = c_r[i]
                col_j = x[j]
                new_df[i+'-Diff'] = col_c - col_j
        
        else:
            break
```

But I keep getting back an empty data frame. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is ```c_r``` ?

Comment: Apologies, I edited my question to answer your question. Both are dataframes with usually the same columns

Comment: Apologies(again),but what is your expected output.When I run you code on two fictive df (```c_r``` and ```x``` as two column df), I get new_df as the difference between them.   Do this: Share a few rows of the two df and how you want the output to look like.

Comment: No need to apologise. Can you please move to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65109811/python-pandas-find-common-columns-between-two-dataframes-and-create-another ? And I can delete this one. The other post is the same question but with way more description!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65127506/6361531  I believe you looping is unneccessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine, but might be unecessary. But if you want to use it. I created the dfs as `c_r` in

```
EOL - CL Per $;Access - CL Per $;Total Impact - CL Per $
-0.02;-0.39;-0.01
-0.02;-0.39;-0.02
-0.02;-0.39;-0.01
-0.02;-0.39;-0.02
```

and `x` in

```
EOL - CL Per $;Access - CL Per $;Total Impact - CL Per $
-0.02;-0.39;0.05
-0.02;-0.39;0.03
-0.02;-0.39;0.06
-0.02;-0.39;0.04
```

And then

```
c_r = pd.read_csv(r"C:/users/k_sego/c_r.csv", sep=";")
x = pd.read_csv(r"C:/users/k_sego/x.csv", sep=";")
```

Your code

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in c_r:
    for j in x:
        if c_r[i].dtype != object and x[j].dtype != object:
            if i == j:
                col_c = c_r[i]
                col_j = x[j]
                new_df[i+'-Diff'] = col_c - col_j
        
        else:
            break
```

works just ok and gives

```
   EOL - CL Per $-Diff  Access - CL Per $-Diff  Total Impact - CL Per $-Diff
0                  0.0                     0.0                         -0.06
1                  0.0                     0.0                         -0.05
2                  0.0                     0.0                         -0.07
3                  0.0                     0.0                         -0.06
```

So,if it doesn'twork for you it must have to do with the files you have.

Comment: Thank you for this btw. This is very strange! Did you apply exactly my code from above? Also, can you please check what version of pandas to do you have?

Comment: pd.__version__  '1.0.5'. Have you checked the dtype of your data?

Comment: Mine is ```'0.25.3'```, I have a feeling that might play a role?

Comment: Haha wise words. I  will do that now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I get the same problem. It doesn't work well. It gives the whole result in the 1st row, at ```index``` 0....